# Getting FlinkRuntime Exception during oracle exactly once jdbc sink

Tags: flink-streaming, ojdbc, exactly-once

I have configured exactly once Jdbc oracle sink in my Flink Streaming application. I followed flink doumentation and coded accordingly. But getting below exception.

```
FlinkRuntimeException:unable to recover , error -3: resource manager error has occurred. [null]
   at org.apache.connector.jdbc.xa.XaFacadeImpl.wrapException(XaFacadeImpl.java: 369)
```

Code:

```
SinkFuntion<F> jdbcSink = JdbcSink.exactlyOnceSink(query, statementBuilder, jdbcOptions, jdbcExactlyOnceOptions, () -> {
oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXADataSource source = new oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXADataSource();
source.setURL(..);
source.setUser(..);
----
return source;
});
```

I expected to work as mentioned but getting runtime exception

Comment: There should be more of the stack frame available from this error. Also see https://developer.jboss.org/thread/72007 for something that seems related.